Wiql Query filtering for ALL child work items
I'm trying to write a Wiql query to return a list of Features where their status is not Closed or Removed and all their child user stories are Closed.
This is my current query:
SELECT
        [System.Id],
        [System.Title],
        [System.AreaPath],
        [System.IterationPath],
        [System.Tags]
FROM workitemLinks
WHERE
        (
                [Source].[System.State] <> 'Closed'
                AND [Source].[System.State] <> 'Removed'
                AND [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature'
        )
        AND (
                [System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward'
        )
        AND (
                [Target].[System.State] <> 'Closed'
                AND [Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story'
        )
ORDER BY [Target Date] ASC
MODE (DoesNotContain)

This returns all Features as described, but also returns all Features that do not have any child user stories at all.
How do I modify this to get it to filter out Features that do not have any child user stories (so it only lists open Features that have user stories which are all closed)?

Based on your description, I generated sample features in the image below.

Your WIQL was equivalent to what was defined in the following query editor, where we could see the item F0 - No Children also satisfied the condition to mismatch the clauses defined for linked work items, when this feature had no child user story at all. Thus, it was also listed in the query results.

I could understand your expectation and I do believe it will be helpful for us to tract the work items whose children are already closed. However, I am afraid that there is no WIQL clause/functionality out-of-the-box at the moment to check if a work item has existing child items. For this, you could create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion . That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.
